# statefull allocators in visual studio? looks a bit broken - is there a way to write a working stateful custom allocator in VS?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, std

Porting some code to VS is not working because the implementation of std::allocator dose not properly support allocators with state.

From the code example that works well on gcc and clang it look like MS tries to actually create 3 allocators instead of 1.

Thanks!

Example (based on code from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator).
Here is some code that works correctly in clang and gcc but not in VS:

//---------------------- start example of code ----------------------------------------

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <new>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
 
using namespace std;

int n=0;

template<class T>
struct Mallocator
{
    typedef T value_type;
 
    int i;
    Mallocator() {
        i = n++;
        cout << "Mallocator::Mallocator " << i << endl;
    }
    ~Mallocator() {
        cout << "Mallocator::~" << i << endl;
    }
 
    template<class U>
    constexpr Mallocator(const Mallocator <U>&u) noexcept {
        i = n++;
        cout << "Mallocator(const Mallocator <U>&) u.i=" << u.i << ", i=" << i << endl;
    }
 
    [[nodiscard]] T* allocate(std::size_t n)
    {
        if (n > std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max() / sizeof(T))
            throw std::bad_array_new_length();
 
        if (auto p = static_cast<T*>(std::malloc(n * sizeof(T))))
        {
            report(p, n);
            return p;
        }
 
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    }
 
    void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t n) noexcept
    {
        report(p, n, 0);
        std::free(p);
    }
private:
    void report(T* p, std::size_t n, bool alloc = true) const
    {
        std::cout << "i=" << i << "  " << (alloc ? "Alloc: " : "Dealloc: ") << sizeof(T) * n
                  << " bytes at " << std::hex << std::showbase
                  << reinterpret_cast<void*>(p) << std::dec << '\n';
    }
    
    using is_always_equal = false_type;
    using propagate_on_container_move_assignment = false_type;

};
 

int main()
{
    
    list<int, Mallocator<int>> l; // = {1,2,3,4};
    l.push_back(1);
    l.push_back(2);
    l.push_back(3);
    
    list<int, Mallocator<int>> l2;
    
    for(auto item : l)
       l2.push_back(item);
    
    cout << "------------" << endl;
}


//---------------------- end example code -----------------------------
```

When running this on https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f612fb49665239e2
result:

```
g++ -std=c++20  -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pthread -pedantic-errors main.cpp -lm  -latomic  && ./a.out
Mallocator::Mallocator 0
i=0  Alloc: 24 bytes at 0x1bed030
i=0  Alloc: 24 bytes at 0x1bed050
i=0  Alloc: 24 bytes at 0x1bed070
Mallocator::Mallocator 1
i=1  Alloc: 24 bytes at 0x1bed090
i=1  Alloc: 24 bytes at 0x1bed0b0
i=1  Alloc: 24 bytes at 0x1bed0d0
------------
i=1  Dealloc: 24 bytes at 0x1bed090
i=1  Dealloc: 24 bytes at 0x1bed0b0
i=1  Dealloc: 24 bytes at 0x1bed0d0
Mallocator::~1
i=0  Dealloc: 24 bytes at 0x1bed030
i=0  Dealloc: 24 bytes at 0x1bed050
i=0  Dealloc: 24 bytes at 0x1bed070
Mallocator::~0
```

As can be seen, there are 2 allocators each responsible for its own items

Same code running on a fresh console app on VS Version 17.8.5 gives a very different result, some 6 (!!!) allocators are created and it seems like the     *using is_always_equal = false_type;* is totally ignored!
Tested with default and CPP+20 variants - same problems.

//------------- VS  17.8.5  output ---------

```
Mallocator::Mallocator 0
Mallocator(const Mallocator <U>&) u.i=0, i=1
i=1  Alloc: 16 bytes at 0000026F18612BF0
i=0  Alloc: 24 bytes at 0000026F1860EE10
Mallocator::~1
i=0  Alloc: 24 bytes at 0000026F1860EDB0
i=0  Alloc: 24 bytes at 0000026F1860F470
i=0  Alloc: 24 bytes at 0000026F1860F530
Mallocator::Mallocator 2
Mallocator(const Mallocator <U>&) u.i=2, i=3
i=3  Alloc: 16 bytes at 0000026F18612C40
i=2  Alloc: 24 bytes at 0000026F1860F590
Mallocator::~3
i=2  Alloc: 24 bytes at 0000026F1860EB10
i=2  Alloc: 24 bytes at 0000026F1860F5F0
i=2  Alloc: 24 bytes at 0000026F1860F650
------------
i=2  Dealloc: 24 bytes at 0000026F1860EB10
i=2  Dealloc: 24 bytes at 0000026F1860F5F0
i=2  Dealloc: 24 bytes at 0000026F1860F650
i=2  Dealloc: 24 bytes at 0000026F1860F590
Mallocator(const Mallocator <U>&) u.i=2, i=4
i=4  Dealloc: 16 bytes at 0000026F18612C40
Mallocator::~4
Mallocator::~2
i=0  Dealloc: 24 bytes at 0000026F1860EDB0
i=0  Dealloc: 24 bytes at 0000026F1860F470
i=0  Dealloc: 24 bytes at 0000026F1860F530
i=0  Dealloc: 24 bytes at 0000026F1860EE10
Mallocator(const Mallocator <U>&) u.i=0, i=5
i=5  Dealloc: 16 bytes at 0000026F18612BF0
Mallocator::~5
Mallocator::~0
```

Answer (score 2):

`_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=1` and `2` cause this weirdness. Setting it to `0` (which is the default in release mode) gives me a good output (except they allocate an extra node per list).

Perhaps they're doing this to help you check your allocators (a copy of the allocator is supposed to be able to work with original's memory), or MSVC STL is just buggy.

Output with `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0`:

```
Mallocator::Mallocator 0
i=0  Alloc: 24 bytes at 00007FFFFE7B2A40
i=0  Alloc: 24 bytes at 00007FFFFE7B2AA0
i=0  Alloc: 24 bytes at 00007FFFFE7B2B00
i=0  Alloc: 24 bytes at 00007FFFFE7B2B60
Mallocator::Mallocator 1
i=1  Alloc: 24 bytes at 00007FFFFE7B2BC0
i=1  Alloc: 24 bytes at 00007FFFFE7B2C20
i=1  Alloc: 24 bytes at 00007FFFFE7B2C80
i=1  Alloc: 24 bytes at 00007FFFFE7B2CE0
------------
i=1  Dealloc: 24 bytes at 00007FFFFE7B2C20
i=1  Dealloc: 24 bytes at 00007FFFFE7B2C80
i=1  Dealloc: 24 bytes at 00007FFFFE7B2CE0
i=1  Dealloc: 24 bytes at 00007FFFFE7B2BC0
Mallocator::~1
i=0  Dealloc: 24 bytes at 00007FFFFE7B2AA0
i=0  Dealloc: 24 bytes at 00007FFFFE7B2B00
i=0  Dealloc: 24 bytes at 00007FFFFE7B2B60
i=0  Dealloc: 24 bytes at 00007FFFFE7B2A40
Mallocator::~0
```

Comment: I would go with "MSVC STL is just buggy." ..  Thanks for having a look at this.

Comment: @QT-1 You could report a bug to them and see what they say. MSVC itself is jank, but their STL is decent.

Comment: I did report a bug, I hoped I was wrong and there is a workaround. I ended up using my own, limits list :( , which is single-linked, partially lock-free and x3 times faster..

Comment: @QT-1 I'm not seeing the ticket here: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues...

Comment: I posted it to VS community via the feedback. Here is the link:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/std::stl-allocator-with-state-is-broken/10565283?port=1025&fsid=7411aaf0-4541-457c-b749-46ef82907c3a&ref=native&refTime=1705926683213&refUserId=a4c1fd31-e988-6545-8a44-93285f27cf9e

Comment: @QT-1 Generally it's a better idea to post the standard library issues to github, you have a better chance of getting a reply there.

Comment: Good idea, I'll try that next time.